# Improving tesseract digit recognition

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract

I am using Tesseract v5.1.0 to identify the digits from the image below using the command:

```
tesseract 146_164.jpg stdout -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789
```

The result is 168 14. What can I do to improve the accuracy?

[image: digits]

Comment: you may need to detect objects on image and rotate them - but this may need complex code using module `cv2` (`OpenCV`). OR you would have to learn tesseract to recognize rotated numbers - but this is more complex task.

Comment: [Improving the quality of the output | tessdoc](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality)

Comment: Hi Furas, I was thinking along the same line. I was trying to use cv2 to place a minimum area rectangle around each character and then extract the characters and either apply tesseract or some other ocr method. Once I have a solution, I will post the code.